# Wordpress Navigation Menus - Showing Empty Categories

Tags: wordpress

Have created a custom navigation menu in wordpress that has some pages and some categories in it as links. Now when I load the menu using default options I have two problems:

**1) the categories with no posts in them are not showing up - How to disable this behaviour?
2) the pages are showing up alphabetically on the menu - how to arrange them properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page calls  `wp_list_categories()` you should pass the argument `&hide_empty=0`.

I had to use this for my site. A bit of Googling tells you more.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/categories-not-showing-up-2

Comment: thats the problem precisely... in my header file I do not use the wp_list_categories function but instead call the wp_nav_menu function to display the navigation menu which in turn has two categories as link items....